# Android Studio emulator camera cannot save photos

Tags: android, camera, android-emulator

Regardless of whether I use an emulated camera or use my webcam as the emulated device's camera, I cannot save photos. My code sets up a new file to save the photo, the camera activity pops up, but after I take the picture, hitting the 'save' or 'accept picture' button doesn't do anything. The only way I can return to my app's activity it by hitting cancel. This code works when I run it on my Galaxy S3, but not an emulated Nexus device. When I set up the device in AVD Manager, I always make sure to enable to set both cameras to either emulated or webcam0, whichever I am using, and I make sure to have an SD card (even though I save to internal memory) and internal storage sufficient for photos. In my manifest, I declare android.permission.INTERNET, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, and android.permission.CAMERA. Any ideas?

Here's my code where I start the camera intent:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent(int position) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile(position);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.v("photo", "photoFile failed.");
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                    Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        } else {
            Log.v("tag", "photoFile was equal to null.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: quick note, you can log errors better by using `Log.e("photo", "photoFile failed.", ex);` instead of `Log.v("photo", "photoFile failed.");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution! The emulated camera wasn't returning because I used a bad directory (selected in `createImageFile` above) for saving the File. I started using the directory returned by `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` and that solved the problem.